# RESX-based localization in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, localization, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to research the theme, but still have not clear understanding whether the RESX-based localization possible in Xamarin.Android. In my personal tries I wasn't able to get any localized strings, but only the neutral culture strings.

I also can see posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004414/localization-for-mobile-cross-platform-using-xamarin-and-issue-with-ios-only) where noted that it should work Android:

> This works fine for Android and windows phone.

But I also can see posts like [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569392/xamarin-ios-localization-using-net) where localization is not going to be working.

So my question is simple. How to build RESX-based localized application for Android in Xamarin?

Comment: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_5_-_application_localization_and_string_resources/

Comment: @Jason, I'm currently migrating our WPF application on Android and it will be really sad, if I can reuse BL (including models and viewmodels), but not resx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Answering to my own question]*

Well, first of all, yes, RESX-based localization in Xamarin.Android is possible and works as expected.

Second, I've lost a lot of time in tries to make it working just due to lack of attention to details. I've read the article [Localizing Xamarin.Forms Apps with RESX Resource Files](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/localization/) several times, but I was always omitting the section Troubleshooting. Exactly there was a key:

> **Doesn't work in DEBUG mode (Android only)**
>
> If the translated strings
> are working in your RELEASE Android builds but not while debugging,
> right-click on the Android Project and select Options > Build >
> Android Build and ensure that the Fast assembly deployment is NOT
> ticked. This option causes problems with loading resources and should
> not be used if you are testing localized apps.

Third, while trying to find some alternative ways of solving my problem, I found interesting the approach described in the article [Generating Localized Resources in Mono for Android Using T4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578158/GeneratingplusLocalizedplusResourcesplusinplusMono). In pair with the cool NuGet package from Daniel Cazzulino described in the article [How to transform T4 templates on build without installing a Visual Studio SDK](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/how-to-transform-t4-templates-on-build-without-installing-a-visual-studio-sdk/) I was able to build a simple alternative for Android platform based on my RESX from WPF project.

Hope it can help somebody.

Comment: Here´s an alternative to Resx, in case anyone is interested: https://github.com/xleon/I18N-Portable

Comment: Wait, you are answering with "yes" but eventually using T4 to create probably xml files to translations? While I have done the same for web-apps to create .json files, the answer to your own question is actually "NO, BUT...you can use T4". Or am I wrong? I still don't have an answer on how to use translations in axml (not xaml) files for Xamarin.Android

Comment: Please can you tell me the final satution that you have implemented and how you accessing string in XML and in Activities?